# lowerCase и upperCase в одной функции vue

Tags: vue.js

Есть фильтрация массива несколькими способами.
Конкретно сейчас интересует lowercase, реализованный для поиска внутри массива. Когда произвожу поиск по массиву, поиск производится только когда ввод происходит на нижнем регистре. Если на клавиатуре с помощью капса переключаю на верхний регистр, поиск (вернее фильтрация) массива не происходит, как изначально это было задумано. Вообще пропадают все данные из массива. 
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Мой код:

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#movieApp',
    data: {
        randomMovie: null,
        randomMovieDescription: null,
        movies: [
            {
                film: "A",
                year: 2012,
                seen: false
            },
            {
                film: "B",
                year: 2012,
                seen: false
            },
            {
                film: "C",
                year: 2013,
                seen: false
            },
            {
                film: "D",
                year: 2019,
                seen: false
            }]
          }, 
          computed: {
          filteredMovies: function () {
          return this.movies.filter(
      m => !m.seen && m.year <= +this.rangeYear && m.film.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search) > -1 && m.film.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search) > -1)}
      
      }
```

Пробовала прописывать помимо lowercase - uppercase. Прописывала фильтры с помощью логического "или", тогда поиск успешно работал с обеими раскладками, но не работали другие фильтры.

Не могли бы скорректировать  меня, что мне нужно сделать, чтобы в моем случае валидными были все виды фильтрации

Comment: к одному регистру надо приводить обе строки и ту в которой происходит поиск и ту которая ищется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
filteredMovies () {
    return this.movies.filter((m) => {
        const search = this.search.toLowerCase();
        const film = m.film.toLowerCase();

        return !m.seen && m.year <= +this.rangeYear && film.includes(search);
    });
}
```